# Log in from magento cli?

Tags: magento2, cli, admin-login

On Drupal I often log in using `drush uli`. It opens a one-time login URL in my browser.

Is it possible to log in to the Magento backend with `bin/magento`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It is not possible currently to log in as an admin using CLI in Magento 2 but you can create a new user like:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user=mageuser --admin-password=HiMagento123 --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-firstname=John --admin-lastname=Doe
```

Or you can check the below command for more details:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --help
```

Answer (score 0):

Natively, I don't think that is possible, you can rather see the **admin URI** like this : `php bin/magento info:adminuri`

To see all the available commands, you can execute : `php bin/magento` or `php bin/magento list`.